# Sieve of Eratosthenes, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, output is composite number

Tags: java, algorithm, boolean, indexoutofboundsexception

I tried writing a Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm, I am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException but I don't seem to understand why, if I change the limits, upon printing it only displays composite numbers, the code's below help if you can.

```
public static Boolean[] solution(int N) {
        Boolean[] isPrime = new Boolean[N];
        isPrime[0] = false;
        for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            isPrime[i] = true;
        }

        for(int i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
            if(isPrime[i]== true) {
                System.out.println(i);
                for(int j = 2; (j * i) < N; j++) {
                    int k = j * i;
                    isPrime[k] = false;
                }

            }
        }

    return isPrime;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i <= N;` cause the error

```
for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            isPrime[i] = true;
}
```

for example

if `N=4` then you get error when `i=4`. `isPrime[4]` cause `OutOfBounds` exception because length is 4.arrays are zero index based. so maximum index you can access is 3.`isPrime[3]`

you can avoid this error by changing loop to `for(int i = 1; i < N; i++) {`

however i'm not sure what is Eratosthenes algorithem is .i hope you can change your code keep in mind arrays are zero index based

Comment: Also, `1` isn't prime, so the loop should start from `2`.

Comment: If a prime number is entered, it is not generated only prime numbers before it appear if the equal sign is removed, the best way to increase accuracy would be to increase the Boolean array size by one, as in:        Boolean[] isPrime = new Boolean[N+1];

Answer (score 1):

`Boolean[N]` creates an array of N elements, so, since the indexes start from 0, the last index is N-1.
The error is caused by `i<=N` in the for loop